# Stata MIXED Extract Intercept, Slope

Tags: stata, store, mixed

```
mixed weight week || id: week
predict u1 u0, reffects
generate intercept = _b[_cons] + u0
generate slope = _b[week] + u1
```

If I wish for to estimate and store id-specific intercept and slope I can use the code above, but when I do it with week-squared (week2) I get errors...

```
mixed weight week week2 || id: week week2
predict u1 u0, reffects
generate intercept = _b[_cons] + u0
generate slope = _b[week] + u1
```

Comment: Your model expresses three random effects terms. As the documentation for `predict` indicates "You must specify q new variables, where q is the number of random-effects terms in the model".  So you need to do something like `predict u*, reffects`

Comment: @langtang i read the documentation and that's why i post here because i keep getting error, can you please assist?

Comment: your model expresses a random intercept, a random effect on `week`, and random effect on `week2`. That is three. Therefore, when you run the `predict` command with the `,reffects` option, you must provide three variable names to hold the random effects estimates. Therefore `predict u1 u2 u3, reffects` will avoid your error